# Conversion of tensor shape values to None in a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

### Suppose I have a simple keras model as follows,

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 8)         224       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1                     (None, 7, 7, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2                     (None, 3, 3, 2)           584       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,392
Trainable params: 1,392
Non-trainable params: 0
```

### Now I want the final output layer shape as follows,

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 8)         224       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1                     (None, 7, 7, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2                     (None, None, None, 2)     584       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,392
Trainable params: 1,392
Non-trainable params: 0
```

### Code

```
m = Sequential()

m.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
m.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), padding='same', strides=2))
m.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), strides=2))
m.add(Conv2D(2, (3,3), strides=2))
```

### Details

> I hope you got an understanding of the issue.
> Please try to make your own versions of the code. This is just a demo code.

I am working on image colorization problem where we input an image with one color channel and get output with 2 color channels.
The original code is huge and different from any codes on the internet. So please don't be concerned about suggesting me any image colorization codes.

I really appreciate it if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Which problem made you to consider making last layer output as (None,None,None, 2)?

Comment: It's an image colorization problem.